# Disable allowing assigning Readonly types to non-readonly types

Tags: typescript, immutability

I've been looking at the readonly type in typescript. Sadly, it does not work as i hope it would. For instance, see the code below:

```
interface User{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

const user: Readonly<User> = {
    firstName: "Joe",
    lastName: "Bob",
};

const mutableUser: User = user; //Is it possible to disallow this?

user.firstName = "Foo" //Throws error as expected
mutableUser.firstName ="Bar"//This works
```

Is it somehow possible to use the readonly type in a way that doesn't allow assigning it to another type that is not readonly? If it isn't can i solve it in any other way?

Comment: Not possible currently.You maybe could do something for  a function parameter to ensure the passed in parameter does not have readonly fields

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/danielnixon/eslint-plugin-total-functions#total-functionsno-unsafe-assignment

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ah, you've run into a problem that annoyed someone enough to file an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13002) with the memorable title ["readonly modifiers are a joke"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13002#event-916346948) (which has since changed to something more neutral).   The issue is being tracked at [Microsoft/TypeScript#13347](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347), but there doesn't seem to be much movement on it.  For now, we just have to deal with the fact that `readonly` properties don't affect assignability.

So, what workarounds are possible?

---

The cleanest is to give up on `readonly` properties and instead use some kind of mapping that turns an object into something you really can only read from, via something like getter functions.  For example, if readonly properties are replaced with functions that return the desired value:

```
function readonly<T extends object>(x: T): { readonly [K in keyof T]: () => T[K] } {
  const ret = {} as { [K in keyof T]: () => T[K] };
  (Object.keys(x) as Array<keyof T>).forEach(k => ret[k] = () => x[k]);
  return ret;
}

const user = readonly({
  firstName: "Joe",
  lastName: "Bob",
});

const mutableUser: User = user; // error, user is wrong shape

// reading from a readonly thing is a bit annoying
const firstName = user.firstName();
const lastName = user.lastName();

// but you can't write to it
user.firstName = "Foo" // doesn't even make sense, "Foo" is not a function
user.firstName = () => "Foo" // doesn't work because readonly
```

Or similarly, if a readonly object only exposes a single getter function:

```
function readonly<T extends object>(x: T): { get<K extends keyof T>(k: K): T[K] } {
  return { get<K extends keyof T>(k: K) { return x[k] } };
}

const user = readonly({
  firstName: "Joe",
  lastName: "Bob",
});

const mutableUser: User = user; // error, user is wrong shape

// reading from a readonly thing is a bit annoying
const firstName = user.get("firstName");
const lastName = user.get("lastName");

// but you can't write to it
user.firstName = "Foo" // doesn't even make sense, firstName not a property
```

It's annoying to use, but definitely enforces the spirit of readonliness (readonlity? ‍♂️) and you can't accidentally write to something readonly.

---

Another workaround is to run a helper function which will only accept mutable values, as [@TitianCernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) has [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412934/disable-allowing-assigning-readonly-types-to-non-readonly-types#comment93700419_53412934).  Possibly, like this:

```
type IfEquals<T, U, Y = unknown, N = never> =
  (<V>() => V extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<V>() => V extends U ? 1 : 2) ? Y : N;
type Mutable<T> = { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
type IsMutable<T, Y=unknown, N=never> = IfEquals<T, Mutable<T>, Y, N>

const readonly = <T>(x: T): Readonly<T> => x;
const mutable = <T>(
  x: T & IsMutable<T, unknown, ["OOPS", T, "has readonly properties"]>
): Mutable<T> => x;

const readonlyUser = readonly({
  firstName: "Joe",
  lastName: "Bob",
});
const mutableUser = mutable(
  { firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Joe" }
); // okay

const fails: User = mutable(readonlyUser); // error, can't turn readonly to mutable
// msg includes ["OOPS", Readonly<{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }>
// , "has readonly properties"]

const works = readonly(mutableUser); //okay, can turn mutable to readonly
```

Here the `readonly` function will accept any value of type `T` and return a `Readonly<T>`, but the `mutable` function will only accept values which are already mutable.  You have to remember to call `mutable()` on any value you expect to be mutable.  That's fairly error-prone, so I don't really recommend this method.

---

I also played around with the idea of making a fake `Readonly<T>` type which modified `T` in such a way as to distinguish it [structurally](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) from `T`, but it was as cumbersome as the getter-function method.  The problem is that, assuming you want to be able to assign mutable values to readonly variables but you want to be prevented from assigning readonly values to mutable variables, the readonly modifier needs to widen the type of `T`, not narrow it.  That limits the options to something like `Readonly<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] | Something}` or `Readonly<T> = T | Something`.  But in each case it becomes very difficult to actually read the readonly properties, since you have to narrow the types back.  If you need boilerplate every time you read a property, you might as well use a getter function.  So, forget that.

---

To wrap up: I think the getter function method is probably your best bet if you really want to enforce properties that cannot be written.  Or maybe you should just give up on `readonly` modifiers, as they are, after all, a joke .

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to know. Thank you for a very detailed answer :)

Comment: `["OOPS", T, "has readonly properties"]` is an *excellent* way of improving Typescript error messages. (Except, I suppose, when `T` is a type like `string[]`, in which case the result is assignable to `T` and you don't get an error message at all.)

Comment: what if the `readonly` is not intent but been involved by `as const`?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question; `readonly` is mutually assignable with mutable, except for arrays in which a mutable array is assignable to a `readonly` array but not vice versa. I’m not sure what “what if” means in this context. Is there some specific problem you’re facing? Can it be a new question post instead of a comment chain on an old possibly-related answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is my crack at it.

I add a symbol property to the the `Mutable` type so that a non-`Mutable` value can't be assigned to it. The symbol is intentionally not exported from the file with the `Mutable` definition, so that it is impossible to create a valid `Mutable` object without going through the `makeMutable` function.

In file Mutable.ts:

```
const mutableMarker = Symbol("mutable marker");
type MutableMarker = typeof mutableMarker;

export type Mutable<T> = {
    -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
} & {
    [mutableMarker]: MutableMarker;
};

export function makeMutable<T>(value: T): Mutable<T> {
    return { ...value, [mutableMarker]: mutableMarker };
}
```

Usage:

```
// Everything should be readonly by default.
interface User {
    readonly firstName: string;
    readonly lastName: string;
}

// This is normal.
const readonlyUser: User = {
    firstName: "Joe",
    lastName: "Bob",
};
// Error. Can't assign to readonly property.
readonlyUser.firstName = "";

// This creates a mutable copy, so the original object won't be modified.
const mutableUser = makeMutable(readonlyUser);
mutableUser.firstName = "";

// This is fine. A readonly variable can be assigned the mutable value.
const works: User = mutableUser;
// Error. Can't assign to readonly property.
works.firstName = "";

// Error. Property '[mutableMarker]' is missing in type 'User'. 
const fails: Mutable<User> = readonlyUser;
```

There is a potential source of bugs if you assign a mutable value to a readonly variable, since code that has access to the original mutable value can mutate it unexpectedly. But that is an orthogonal issue, I think.