# Prevent assigning to readonly property

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to fail the compilation of the code like in the example below:

```
interface Ro {
    readonly x: string;
}

const modify = (rw: {x: string;}) => rw.x = 'bye';
const use = (v: Ro) => {
    console.log(v.x);

    //v.x = 'bye'; Compiler error: "Cannot assign to 'x' because it is a read-only property."
    modify(v);// No errors, not even warnings.
}
const ro: Ro = {x: "hi"}
use(ro);
console.log(ro.x);// readonly field has been changed!
```

Comment: That's crazy, I wouldn't expect that [you can assign a readonly property to a non-readonly property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHtkG8BQz-JQRwAm6IANgJ7IAeAXMgM5hSgDmA3DgL446hIsRCgByGbHgINmrDtz44E5FnUYSAvJIJrkAIjIALPb37KQqkDPGYttbkA)

Comment: And there's an [open bug on github for it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347)

Comment: https://www.banterly.net/2021/08/20/the-readonly-lie-of-typescript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [not a way to fail the compilation currently](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347). There are a few things you can do alternatively:

- Use [a lint rule](https://github.com/danielnixon/eslint-plugin-total-functions#total-functionsno-unsafe-readonly-mutable-assignment)
- Use the technique suggested here which is pretty awkward: [Disable allowing assigning Readonly types to non-readonly types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412934/disable-allowing-assigning-readonly-types-to-non-readonly-types)
- Be satisfied with a run-time error using `Object.freeze`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way to achieve this is to use `Object.freeze` on the entire object.

Note: this will only apply at run time, the compilation will succeed

Comment: You need a disclaimer that alternatively, you can use `Object.freeze`. This does not help with compilation.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't help with compilation, it will only act at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
const modify = (rw: {x: string;}) => rw.x = 'bye';
```

you're telling TypeScript to be more lenient than it should be. If you typed the argument correctly `const modify = (rw: Ro) => //...`, it would correctly disallow modification.

If we want, we can pretty much *always* bypass TypeScript safeguards and type checks, by writing things like like `myVariable as unknown as any`, or `Object.defineProperty` etc. It's not bulletproof.

Comment: But it's the wrong behavior. See https://www.banterly.net/2021/08/20/the-readonly-lie-of-typescript/ . Comparing `as unknown as any` to assigning a readonly property to a writable property is comparing apples to oranges. In the first, you're clearly indicating that you don't care about type safety. In the second, the type system is deceiving you and allowing the assignment of a readonly property to an interface that has a mutable property.